# Can I append an angular component to an SVG

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg, webpack

I am trying to create a network topology map using d3 and svg. Under the covers looks like this:

[image]

What I am attempting to do is when a user clicks on a node, I add a rect which I want to inject my Angular component.

```
 const popRect = me.svg.select('.agent-popover');

        popRect
            .append('svg:rect')
            .attr('x', d.x)
            .attr('y', d.y)
            .attr('width', 200)
            .attr('height', 200);

        popRect
            .append('agent-popover');
```

Is this possible? The  shows to be attached in the Dev Tools DOM, but isn't showing on the screen.

---

UPDATE:

I was able to get this to work by using ViewContainerRef and setting my component up like this and then changing the coordinates of the foreignObject to place it where it needed to go:

```
 <svg:g [zoomableOf]="network" class="zoom-container" >
        <svg:g class="links" ></svg:g>
        <svg:g class="nodes"></svg:g>
        <svg:g class="securities"></svg:g>
        <svg:g class="agent-popover">
            <svg:foreignObject x="100" y="100" height="200" width="200">
                <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
            </svg:foreignObject>
        </svg:g>
    </svg:g>
```

Now, I need to figure out how to remove/hide the component when I close it.

Comment: That's not how to dynamically insert angular components, check out `ViewContainerRef` API doc for more information

Comment: Ok, I have read up on ViewContainerRef https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286 .. but it looks like I would need to add an <ng-template #dyanmic> to my svg and then attach the component. I don't think that is possible.

Comment: That's the point I was implying